# Playbook dependencies vs Role Dependency

Tags: ansible

I've started out using ansible and I'm wondering what the best practice is for using multiple roles in a playbook or specifying multiple role dependencies. Example: consider a role name `common`. This role exists to share common config across all things in the site. Then there are roles like `web`, `db`, or `mail` etc. In practice these require the `common` role. So the question is: Should such a thing be expressed in a playbook that creates machines for the different roles or specified as role dependencies? Is there any trade-offs which one approach or the other. I lean towards specifying them as role dependencies.

How have you done it before?

Answer (score 2):

A role dependency is appropriate if a role really is depending on that other role, like installing some requirements first, before they can be used etc. So if `common` indeed installs requirements then it qualifies for a role dependency. It should not be a role dependency if it does completely unrelated things.

The name `common` suggests it might actually be doing multiple things that just happen to be executed on all hosts. Instead I suggest you really think in *roles*. All hosts might have Apache, MySQL and PHP installed. That does not mean it all has to be stuffed into a single role. Make it 3 roles, small packages. It then should get obvious which role is a dependency of another role or if it should be added on the playbook level.